# RelativeLayout height in onCreate is 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I 'm trying to dynamically adjust the height of my rows depending on the (screen height - my layout height) / list.size.

Unfortunately in the onCreate method the layout height returns null (not so when i call it in an on click listener).

Is there another method I can call it in?
I want Height and width at runtime.

Help me....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

in onCreate views havent been laid, so it returns null always, you need to set GlobalLayoutListener, and then in onGlobalLayout method of the listener you can fetch actual dimensions of view/layout.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //in here, place the code that requires you to know the dimensions.


         //this will be called as the layout is finished, prior to displaying.
    }
}
```